# Get values from html elements in table with multiple rows

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm trying to get input element values from a table that is generated by PHP on foreach. Obviously each line must have it's unique `id=""`.
Each row has a save button. This save button must send, along with `id="regular_hours" value="?"` and `id="shift_type" value="?"` in the form/row to ajax individually ONCE pressing on the save button.

The code below shows the HTML/PHP part:

````
```<?php foreach ($TimesheetList = $Timesheet->GetEmployeeTimesheetDetails() as $List) { ?>
<form class="add-new-user pt-0 fv-plugins-bootstrap5 fv-plugins-framework" onsubmit="return false" novalidate="novalidate">
    <tr>
        <td><input disabled type="text" id="date" class="form-control form-control-sm datePicker date" placeholder="Date" value="<?= $TimeFormat->FormatDate($List['date']); ?>"></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="regular_hours" name="regular_hours[]" class="form-control form-control-sm regular_hours" placeholder="00:00" value="<?= $TimeFormat->FormatTime($List['hours_worked']); ?>"></td>
        <td>
            <select id="shift_type" name="shift_type[]" class="form-control form-control-sm">
                <option value="" disabled selected>Select Shift</option>
                <?php foreach ($Effortlist = $Effort->GetShiftTypes() as $Shift){ ?>
                   <option value="<?= $Shift['id']; ?>"><?= $Shift['title']; ?></option>
                <?php }; ?>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <button type="submit" id="<?= isset($List['data_id']) ? $List['data_id'] : ''; ?>" name="editTimesheet" class="btn btn-icon btn-primary btn-sm editTimesheet">
            <span class="tf-icons bx bx-save"></span>
            </button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</form>
<?php }; ?>```
````

So in JQuery/Javascript, I'm trying to get the following data from each individual row in a table:

- <button id="" (working already individually)
- <input id="regular_hours" value= ??
- <select id="shift_type"  -> <option value="??"

`<button id=""` from each row in the table is being fetched properly by css class name `editTimesheet`, however values from the two other elements `<input id="regular_hours" value=""` `<input id="shift_type" value=""` , won't be fetched as I'm getting confused after 4 hours trying to figure this out

````
    ```// edit timesheet
        $('.editTimesheet').each(function() {
            $(this).click(function(){
    
                var id          = $(this).attr('id'); <-- working
                var regular     = $(this).attr('regular_hours'); <-- NOT working
                var shift_type  = $("#shift_type option:selected").val(); <-- NOT working
                //var shift_type = $("#shift_type option:selected").val();
                //var shift_type = id.find('#position').val();
                
                var info = {
                    id: id,
                    regular: regular,
                    shift_type: shift_type
                };
                editTimesheet(info);
            });
        });

function editTimesheet(info)
{
    $.ajax(
    {
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "../../api/office/my-timesheets/edit",
        data: JSON.stringify(info),
        cache: false,
        async: true,
        success: function (result)
        {
            if (result.success == 'true')
            {
                console.info("success");
                Swal.fire(
                {
                    type: "success",
                    title: 'Success',
                    text: 'Timesheet row edited successfully',
                    confirmButtonClass: 'btn btn-warning',
                }).then((result) =>
                {
                    location.reload();
                });
            }
        },
        error: function (result)
        {
            console.info("Error");
            toastr.warning('System Error 47001. Cannot connect to server to process your request.');
        },
    });
}```
````

[Screenshot of table with button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u01Jj.png)

At this point i'm kind of stuck, however as the button is already working, I hope somebody can help me out!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change like this

`id="date"` to `id="date<?= $List['data_id']; ?>"`

`id="regular_hours"` to `id="regular_hours <?= $List['data_id']; ?>"`

`id="shift_type"` to `id="shift_type<?= $List['data_id']; ?>"`

```
$('.editTimesheet').click(function(){
   var id          = $(this).attr('id');
   var regular     = $('#regular_hours' + id).val();
   var shift_type  = $("#shift_type + id").find(':selected').val();
                
   var info = {
       id: id,
       regular: regular,
       shift_type: shift_type
   };
   editTimesheet(info);
});
```

Comment: It's working~ thank you so much! haven't thought about putting the ID's in there :)

Comment: Could you except the answer ?